# Why do changing the limits of RandomInteger not affect the result?

Tags: random

Recently I noticed (on Windows 10, Mathematica 12.1) that changing the limits of `RandomInteger`, while keeping `SeedRandom` fixed, does not affect the result and produces a weird <s>non-random</s> non-pseudo random pattern. For example,

```
Table[SeedRandom[12345678]; RandomInteger[{1, i}], {i, 2, 50}]
```

returns

```
{2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 13, 13, 13, 13, 9, 9, 9, 9, 21, 21,21, 21, 21, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18}
```

Naively I would expect that by changing the range of the random numbers would affect the result, as the chance to get a random integer in the range [1,4] is not the same as in [1,5] even with a fixed `SeedRandom`.

Moreover, this seems to be affected by the method used in the `SeedRandom` function:

```
CountDistinct[Table[SeedRandom[12345678, Method -> #];RandomInteger[{1, i}], {i, 2, 9999}]] & /@ {"Congruential","ExtendedCA", "Legacy", "MersenneTwister", "MKL", "Rule30CA"}
```

returns the number of distinct numbers

```
{35, 12, 25, 25, 7514, 25}
```

which implies that using the MKL method (only available for Intel processors) offers the largest variety.

However, `RandomReal` gives very different results:

```
CountDistinct[Table[SeedRandom[12345678, Method -> #];RandomReal[{1, i}], {i, 2, 9999}]] & /@ {"Congruential","ExtendedCA", "Legacy",MersenneTwister", "MKL", "Rule30CA"}

{9998, 9998, 9998, 9998, 9998, 9998}
```

So, what is going on here? Is there some sort of weird bug in `RandomInteger` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is expected. Consider the following implementation of `RandomInteger`:

```
randomBit[] := RandomInteger[{0, 1}]
rand[{min_, max_}] :=
 Module[
  {diff, n, res = Infinity},
  diff = max - min;
  n = Ceiling@Log2[max - min + 1];
  While[res > diff,
   res = FromDigits[Table[randomBit[], n], 2]
   ];
  min + res
  ]
```

Note that we use `RandomInteger[{0,1}]` internally to generate single random bits using Mathematica's RNG. The numbers are then generated by generating `n` random bits, where `n` is the smallest number of bits that can represent the required number of different outcomes (e.g. `n==3` when we need `8` outcomes). We then convert these bits into a number. If the number is too large, we try again, otherwise we return it (this is called [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)). E.g. if we want a number between `0` and `5`, the following could happen:

- We need 3 bits, since 2 bits can only represent 4 different outcomes
- So we generate 3 bits, e.g. `{1, 1, 0}`, which is `6`
- This is too high, so we try again and get e.g. `{1, 0, 0}`, which is `4`
- This is ok, so we return it.

We can verify that this seems to be the internal mechanism used by `RandomInteger`:

```
SeedRandom[12345678];
res1 = RandomInteger[{3, 10}, 10]
(* {3, 8, 6, 5, 4, 4, 10, 7, 9, 3} *)

SeedRandom[12345678];
res2 = Table[rand[{3, 10}], 10]
(* {3, 8, 6, 5, 4, 4, 10, 7, 9, 3} *)

res1 == res2
(* True *)
```

We can now also explain what you are seeing: Let say we generate a number in the ranges `{0,5}`, `{0,6}` and `{0,7}`, all with the same seed. In all cases, we need 3 bits, so let's say we got `{1, 0, 0}` again, which is `4`. Since in all 3 cases, `4` is a valid answer, we return it, resulting in the same result in all cases.

As for the other methods: It looks like both `"Legacy"` and `"MKL"` use different strategies for `RandomInteger`, where obviously the one used by `"MKL"` does not have this particular behavior.

#### Update

It seems we can reproduce the results from `"MKL"` using the following strategy:

```
randomBits[n_] := IntegerDigits[RandomInteger[{0, 2^31 - 1}], 2, 31][[;; n]]

rand[{min_, max_}] :=
 Module[
  {diff, n, res = Infinity},
  diff = max - min;
  n = Ceiling@Log2[max - min + 1];
  While[res > diff,
   res = FromDigits[randomBits[n], 2]
   ];
  min + res
  ]

SeedRandom[12345678, Method -> "MKL"];
res1 = RandomInteger[{3, 10}, 10]
(* {9, 6, 7, 9, 3, 7, 8, 6, 5, 7} *)

SeedRandom[12345678, Method -> "MKL"];
res2 = Table[rand[{3, 10}], 10]
(* {9, 6, 7, 9, 3, 7, 8, 6, 5, 7} *)

res1 == res2
(* True *)
```

The overall method is the same, we simply extract all `n` bits from a single 31 bit integer (no idea why not 32).

Comment: Crystal clear answer, many thanks. The behavior I noticed now makes perfect sense and I learned a lot about how RandomInteger works internally. I will wait a bit before accepting the answer, as is customary.